# How to get the npm packages installed links

Tags: npm

I want to get a list links or the domains that the npm packages get downloaded when the npm install command run.
How can i do this. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your query.

---

Open package-lock.json file which is automatically created once you install a package using `npm install package-name` command. Inside this JSON file, you'll find a list of packages installed as values to the `dependencies` property. Each package is represented here as a JSON object having a `resolved` property whose value maps to the URL of that package.